# Textbook error? Or my own error?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Here is the question find $E(X\mid Y=y)$ when $f(x,y) = 6(1-y)$ on the region $0 \le x \le y \le 1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

In setting this up I first found $f_y = \int_0^y 6-6y \ dx$ which yields $f_y = 6(y-y^2)$

From here, I used the formula for finding the conditional expected value hence: $\int_0^1\int_x^1\frac{6y(1-y)}{6(y-y^2)}\ dy\ dx$ which reduces to $\int_0^1\int_x^1 \ dy \ dx = \frac{1}{2}$

The answer in the back of my book says that it should be $\frac{y}{2}$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the formula you use in the second part? Using $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y=y] = \frac{\int_{0}^1 x f(x,y)dx}{\int_{0}^1 f(x,y)dx}$, I do find $\frac{y}{2}$.

Comment: In general $E(X|Y=y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} yp(x|y)$ OOOOOH, I get it, I did y instead of x. 2nd facepalm of the night.